# Related Rates Problem about moving shadow

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have another question about related rates. I have been asked the following question about related rates. It's been a while since I looked at related rates. I appreciate if anyone can help me with this one:

A street light is mounted at the top of a pole that is $6m$ tall. A man $2m$ tall walks away from the pole with a speed of $2\ m/s$ along a straight path. How fast is the tip of the shadow moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Draw a picture.  Let the lamp post be along the $y$ axis, so the lamp is at $(0,6)$  If the man's feet are at $(x,0)=(2t,0)$, his head is at ???? and the shadow tip is at ???? Now take the derivative of the shadow tip position with respect to $t$.  Depending on how you expressed it, you may need the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem deserves a little discussion.  The question changes depending upon whether we interpret it to mean "how fast is the tip of the shadow moving"

1. with respect to the light source? or,
2. with respect to the base of the pole? or,
3. with respect to the man's feet?

Generally, it seems that elsewhere on the web, this type of question usually refers to interpretation number 2, viz., "how fast is the tip of the shadow moving with respect to the base of the pole."  But that interpretation is not necessary.

Here, it seems we must assume that either the 2nd or 3rd interpretation was intended because I don't believe there is sufficient information provided to calculate the 1st.  A little care must be exercised depending upon whether interpretation 2 or 3 is adopted.

Drawing a picture results in two similar triangles, one "embedded" in the other with heights 6 and 2 respectively.    We are told that $dx \over dt$ = 2 m/s.  We can designate the length of the line segment from the base of the pole to the man's feet as ***x*** and the length of the base of the large triangle ***l***.  We can therefore designate the length of the base of the small triangle from the man's feet to the tip of the shadow as ***u***, a variable that we may or may not use depending upon our interpretation of the question.

**Interpretation 2**

If we assume that we are seeking the rate of change of the tip of the shadow from the base of the pole (with respect to time), then we are interested in $dl \over dt$.  We can use properties of similar triangles to describe the relationship between length ***l*** and length ***x***.  That relationship is $${6 \over 2}={l \over l-x}$$ $$l = {3x \over 2}$$  Differentiating both sides with respect to time, we get $${dl \over dt} = {3 \over 2}{dx \over dt}$$ Substituting 2 m/s for $dx \over dt$ we have $${dl \over dt} = {3 \over 2}*2$$ $${dl \over dt} = 3 m/s$$

**Interpretation 3**

If we assume that we are seeking the rate of change of the tip of the shadow from the the man's feet (with respect to time), then we are interested in $du \over dt$. We use similar triangles as we did above to find that $${du \over dt} = {1 \over 2} * 2$$ $${du \over dt} = 1 m/s$$